# Unexpected token import(ReactJS & Babel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

When I try to run my application, I get following error: 
`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Row } from '../grid'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

I tried a couple of stackoverflow answers that suggested I install `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-preset-es2015`

then configure my `babel-rc` file as such:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "es2015", "react", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"],
    ["transform-class-properties"],
    [
      "import",
      { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": "css" }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But none of these has worked.

Here is the snippet of my webpack.config.js that should configure `babel-loader` to transpile `.jsx|.js`

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your .babelrc should look like

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

Which means you should have

```
"@babel/core": "^7.0.0"
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0"
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0"
```

as dev dependencies.

This all that is necessary to enable the standard features in babel including import and JSX support.  Remove any babel packages that are not these three unless you are also using babel pollyfills.

Comment: I've done that but now I am greeted with a new error: `Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory "C:\\Users\\dkalu\\e-process\\Projects\\Practive app\\Brokers"`

Comment: run `npm install`

Comment: try @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react in the .babelrc  It should be resolving them with or without the preset prefix but maybe something is funky.

Comment: Exactly how I have it and it still doesn't work. Funny it was working this morning then as soon as I restarted that app, it broke!

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling.

Comment: Still no luck. I am still getting `Error: Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory "C:\\Users\\dkalu\\e-process\\Projects\\Practive app\\Brokers"
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180891/discussion-between-dave-kalu-and-deadron).

Answer (score 0):

Your .babelrc should look like

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

if you have not already added babel to dev dependencies, run

`npm i @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --save-dev`

OR

`yarn --dev add @babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react`

this would ensure you have the latest versions of all the required dependencies.